# use sprintf to affect the content of an array and char* to another array of char

Tags: c

I'm not a c programmer, I know only the basics. During my work, I've had to deal with someone else c code. this code gives a segmentation fault when i run it. I've used gdb to debug it, it turned out that the cause of the error is the use of "sprintf".
here is part of the code that illustrates the problem:

```
    char* ptr
    char str0 [1000]
    char str1 [1000]
    .
    .
    .
    sprintf(str1," some text %s some other text %s ",ptr+1,str0);
```

I understand that there is an overflow, but i can't how sprintf works, or how to trunk the second array ( str0) in order to meet the first one size.

Thanks a lot

Comment: What is `ptr` set to? It's not initialized in the code you're showing. So `ptr+1` will cause a fault if it's not since `sprintf` is going to attempt to access a string at the address given by the value of `ptr + 1` (number that's stored in the `ptr` variable plus 1).

Comment: You're probably overrunning a buffer, but we can't tell from what you've given us.  Please update your question with a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `snprintf(str1,sizeof(str1), " some text %s some other text %s ",ptr+1,str0);` write at most `sizeof(str1)` bytes (including the terminating null byte ('\0')) to `str1`.

Comment: Note that if `str0` is at maximum length of 999, then there is no space left in `str1` for any more characters. You could specify maximum widths, taking into account the number of characters in `"some text"` and `"some other text"`, e.g, with `%485s` and `%485s`, or some other appropriate widths, to prevent overflow of `str1`, or enlarge `str1`.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the code to use `snprintf()` instead, that takes an extra argument and checks so that the formatted string doesn't overflow the buffer:

```
snprintf(str1, sizeof str1, " some text %s some other text %s ",ptr+1,str0);
```

This has nothing to do with the pointer addition, that's just a way to skip the first character of whatever string `ptr1` is pointing at.

Answer (score 0):

There could be two reasons.

1. ptr is not pointing to a valid memory as you have not shown it's initialization in your code snippet
2. sprintf works similar to printf but writes the entire sting to a buffer instead of the console. Here you are writing a string to str1 which can hold 1000 characters as per the declaration. But length of the string you are writing is (length of string pointed by (ptr+1) whose size we do not know + length of string pointed by str0 which can be maximum of 1000 + few more charecters required for your text inside the quote). There is a good possibility that you writing more than 1000 chars to str1 which can cause segmentation fault.

Comment: A 3rd reason might be that `str0` is not properly `0`-terminated.